# js path img src load from array[] and cached but still laggy

Tags: javascript, ajax, gsap

So, maybe because I am a beginner with js or whatever but I have a multiple image animations that had some performances issues.

(my DOM :

```
<img id="earth-sprite" src="" />
```

)

What I have :

```
var images = [
    imgPath + 'earth-png/a1.png',
    imgPath + 'earth-png/a2.png',
    imgPath + 'earth-png/a3.png',
    imgPath + 'earth-png/a4.png',
    ...
```

imgPath is a {% static 'path' %} from django

then I have my 'load' :

```
function loadImgs() {
        if (i < totalImg) {
            if (i < 20) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: images[i],
                    crossDomain: true,
                    xhrFields: {
                        withCredentials: false
                    },
                    complete: function() {
                        i++;
                        loadImgs();                     
                    }
                });
            }
          };
```

And then, the tween animation, in order for you to understand why I don't use the DOM:

```
var earthSpine = new TimelineMax();

        earthSpine
            .to(obj, 0.7, {
                curImg: images.length,
                roundProps: "curImg",
                immediateRender: true,
                ease: Linear.easeNone,
                onUpdate: function() {
                    //next image on update
                    earthSprite.src = images[obj.curImg];                   
                }
            });
```

Then, **when I analyse the xhr request**, I see that **everything is cached on memory**, but when I scroll (animation display on scroll) **the server is still sending GET request** :(

Am I doing it wrong ?

I would bless any help haha,

cheers

Comment: I'd start with putting a breakpoint in the debugger where you do your ajax call right before you scroll. You can also log in debugger which images you're requesting.

Comment: On a seperate note I would move the `if ( i < totalImg)` to the `complete: function(){ /** if condition loadImgs(); */ }`

Comment: Well, when I check the network, I can see that the images are cached, then it tries to call it again, figure it's already cached then cancelled the load...
It's really weird, there must be something I am doing wrong.

Comment: I think what you are observing is normal behaviour. If you open **Network** tab in **DevTools** in **Chrome**, under the **Status** column, what are the status codes you are seeing for your image content? Take a look at **[this](https://youtu.be/AXGB4tIRNgM?t=1m40s)** video for a bit explanation on the subject.